# React - Hooks + Context - Is this a good way to do global state management?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, react-hooks, react-context

**I am trying to find a good, clean, with little boilerplate, way to handle React's global state**

The idea here is to have a HOC, taking advantage of React's new Hooks & Context APIs, that returns a Context provider with the value bound to its state. I use rxjs for triggering a state update on store change.

I also export a few more objects from my store (notably : the raw rxjs subject object and a Proxy of the store that always returns the latest value).

This works. When I change something in my global store, I get updates anywhere in the app (be it a React component, or outside React). However, to achieve this, the HOC component re-renders.

**Is this a no-op ?**

The piece of code / logic I think could be problematic is the HOC component:

```js
const Provider = ({ children }) => {
    const [store, setStore] = useState(GlobalStore.value)

    useEffect(() => {
        GlobalStore.subscribe(setStore)
    }, [])

    return <Context.Provider value={store}>{children}</Context.Provider>
}
```

`GlobalStore` is a rxjs `BehaviorSubject`. Every time the subject is updated, the state of the `Provider` component gets updated which triggers a re-render.

Full demo is available there: https://codesandbox.io/s/qzkqrm698q

The real question is: **isn't that a poor way of doing global state management ? I feel it might be because I basically re-render everything on state update...**

**EDIT**: I think I have written a more performant version that's not as lightweight (depends on MobX), but I think it generates a lot less overhead (demo at: https://codesandbox.io/s/7oxko37rq) - Now what would be cool would be to have the same end result, but dropping MobX - The question makes no sense anymore

Comment: Your demo doesn't work.

Comment: How ? What's the problem ?

Comment: `TypeError
Cannot create proxy with a non-object as target or handler` store.js line 44

Comment: Oops, thanks for pointing that out. It's because I was also experimenting with saving store to local storage and since I already had a store in my storage, it worked fine, but it had a bug. It's fixed now. Sorry

Comment: Checkout MobX and [MST](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-state-tree) specifically it kind of embodies what you are trying to implement here.

Comment: @jayarjo the whole point here is to not have to use MobX anymore. I use it in (almost) all my React projects but I'm trying to find a better way than relying on a large dependency like MobX for when I need simpler global state management.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your need to handle a global state. I already found myself in the same situation. We have adopted similar solutions, but in my case, I've decided to completelly drop from ContextAPI.

The ContextAPI really sucks to me. It seems to pretend to be a controller based pattern, but you end up wrapping the code inside an non-sense HOC. Maybe I've missed he point here, but in my opinion the ContextAPI is just a complicated way to offer **scoped** based data flow.

So, I decided to implement my own **global** state manager, using React Hooks and RxJS. Mainly because I do not use to work on really huge projects (where Redux would fit perfectly).

My solution is very simple. So lets read some codes because they say more than words:

### **1. Store**

I've created an class only to *dar nome aos bois* (it's a popular brazilian expression, google it ) and to have a easy way to use partial update on BehaviorSubject value:

```js
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";

export default class Store<T extends Object> extends BehaviorSubject<T> {
  update(value: Partial<T>) {
    this.next({ ...this.value, ...value });
  }
}
```

### **2. createSharedStore**

An function to instantiate the Store class (yes it is just because I don't like to type `new` ¯\*(ツ)*/¯):

```js
import Store from "./store";

export default function <T>(initialValue: T) {
  return new Store<T>(initialValue);
}
```

### **3. useSharedStore**

I created an hook to easily use an local state connected with the `Store`:

```js
import Store from "./store";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { skip } from "rxjs/operators";
import createSharedStore from "./createSharedStore";

const globalStore = createSharedStore<any>({});

type SetPartialSharedStateAction<S> = (state: S) => S;
type SetSharedStateAction<S> = (
  state: S | SetPartialSharedStateAction<S>
) => void;

export default function <T>(
  store: Store<T> = globalStore
): [T, SetSharedStateAction<T>] {
  const [state, setState] = useState(store.value);

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = store
      .pipe(skip(1))
      .subscribe((data) => setState(data));
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  });

  const setStateProxy = useCallback(
    (state: T | SetPartialSharedStateAction<T>) => {
      if (typeof state === "function") {
        const partialUpdate: any = state;
        store.next(partialUpdate(store.value));
      } else {
        store.next(state);
      }
    },
    [store]
  );

  return [state, setStateProxy];
}
```

### **4. ExampleStore**

Then I export individual stores for each feature that needs shared state:

```js
import { createSharedStore } from "hooks/SharedState";

export default createSharedStore<Models.Example | undefined>(undefined);
```

### **5. ExampleComponent**

Finally, this is how to use in the component (just like a regular React state):

```js
import React from "react";
import { useSharedState } from "hooks/SharedState";
import ExampleStore from "stores/ExampleStore";

export default function () {
  // ...
  const [state, setState] = useSharedState(ExampleStore);
  // ...

  function handleChanges(event) {
    setState(event.currentTarget.value);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{state.foo}</h1>
      <input onChange={handleChange} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Here's something similar: https://github.com/leandrohsilveira/reactjs-hooks-rxjs

Answer (score 0):

`GlobalStore` subject is redundant. RxJS observables and React context API both implement pub-sub pattern, there are no benefits in using them together this way. If `GlobalStore.subscribe` is supposed to be used in children to update the state, this will result in unnecessary tight coupling.

Updating glubal state with new object will result in re-rendering the entire component hierarchy. A common way to avoid performance issues in children is to pick necessary state parts and make them pure components to prevent unnecessary updates:

```
<Context.Consumer>
  ({ foo: { bar }, setState }) => <PureFoo bar={bar} setState={setState}/>
</Context.Provider>
```

`PureFoo` won't be re-rendered on state updates as long as `bar` and `setState` are the same.

Comment: I understand your point with `GlobalStore`'s redundancy, but I made it that way because I also want to access the global store outside of React's context. Using rxjs allows me to have the latest state anywhere in my app, which is what I want.

Comment: What's the rest of the app? Is it React? A reasonable approach would be to lift up React global state to the point it will wrap app app parts that depend on it.

Comment: There's no rest of the app. I've been really frustrated by global state management in all of my React projects and have always relied on third parties (mostly MobX) to do it for me. I'm trying to find a more generic, less dependant, lighter way to do it.

I've update my demo, trying to optimise it, but I think it's just worse than it used to be. I can't seem to be able to correctly figure it out.

Comment: I don't see problems with *I also want to access the global store outside of React's context* then, you can access a store inside `App` component if it's context consumer, there's no need for an observable. That's correct, third-party libs aren't necessary but some lessons can be learned from their design.